# How to keep last column of same column names?

Tags: r, dataframe

| Patient | Patient |
| --- | --- |
| chris | chris |
| chris | jake |
| tom | alvin |

As you can see there are same column name but I only want the those on the right.

Sample code

```
x = read_excel(path, sheet=1)
df = data.frame(x)
df <- df [, !duplicated(colnames(df), fromLast = TRUE)]
```

But the output is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`readxl::read_excel()` has the argument `.name_repair` to control how duplicated column names are handled when importing an Excel file. By default it is set to `"check_unique"`. Try `.name_repair = "minimal"`. You may want to check other options, see `?tibble`, Arguments section.

```
x <- readxl::read_excel("./test.xlsx", .name_repair = "minimal")
df <- x[, !duplicated(colnames(x), fromLast = TRUE)]
```

Output:

```
> df
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  Hospital  Ward Patient Staff
  <chr>    <dbl> <chr>   <chr>
1 abc        123 chris   Jen  
2 def        456 ron     Jen  
3 ghi        123 harry   Jen
```